# Office UI fabric JS Dropdown component not loading correct style when its click

Tags: outlook-addin, office-ui-fabric

I am working with Outlook Add-in with Office UI fabric js UI components. I am having issue using dropdown.

[image: Dropdown]

When click on a drop down it doesn't show the dropdown list style and it opens a complete new panel with options.

[image]

I followed this [link](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/Dropdown/Dropdown.html) to add drop down component.

Answer (score 3):

The [dropdown](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/dropdown) component has a prop called `responsiveMode`. This dictates how the [container is rendered](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/09d099ec624afed8b92c5e32277a9a15c5d3c607/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.tsx#L348).

As you can see, for `ResponsiveMode.medium` and below, a [Panel](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/panel) gets rendered, otherwise it will be a [Callout](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/callout).  What you want is the `Callout`.

You just have to pass in the prop `ResponsiveMode.large` for it to render the way you want.

```
import { Dropdown, IDropdownOption } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Dropdown';
import { ResponsiveMode } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/utilities/decorators/withResponsiveMode';

render() {
  return (
    <Dropdown
      label='My Label'
      options={myOptions}
      responsiveMode={ResponsiveMode.large}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @choobs for your answer. But I was look at Office UI fabric JS not the Office UI Fabric React component

Comment: My mistake. If you're not using the React library, it looks like the concept is the [same](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/blob/master/src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.ts#L161). Although in this case it will automatically read the window size so I'm not sure how you would override that here without either modifying the source code or using your own css.